# I am unable to capture and record simultaneously on a button check my code and guide

Tags: android

I am having problem in capturing and recording , I want to capture an image on single click and when  I tap and hold the button it should start recording and stops on releasing the button

```
mStillImageButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS:
                    checkWriteStoragePermission();
                    lockFocus();
                    return true;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // PRESSED

                    mIsRecording = true;
                    mStillImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_radio_button_checked_black_24dp);
                    checkWriteStoragePermission();
                    return true; 

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // RELEASED
                    mChronometer.stop();
                    mChronometer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    mIsRecording = false;
                    mIsTimelapse = false;
                    mStillImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_camera_24dp);
                    mMediaRecorder.stop();
                    mMediaRecorder.reset();
                    mMediaRecorder.release();

                    Intent mediaStoreUpdateIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                    mediaStoreUpdateIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(new File(mVideoFileName)));
                    sendBroadcast(mediaStoreUpdateIntent);

                    startPreview();
                    break;
                    //return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**Here is my recording code**

```
private void startRecord() {

    try {
        if(mIsRecording) {
            setupMediaRecorder();
        } else if(mIsTimelapse) {
            setupTimelapse();
        }
        SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
        Surface previewSurface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
        Surface recordSurface = mMediaRecorder.getSurface();
        mCaptureRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
        mCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);
        mCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(recordSurface);

        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(previewSurface, recordSurface, mImageReader.getSurface()),
                new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                        mRecordCaptureSession = session;
                        try {
                            mRecordCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(
                                    mCaptureRequestBuilder.build(), null, null
                            );
                        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {

                    }
                }, null);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you facing in this code , please share logcat error message .

Comment: Please share the code of recording too .

Comment: Android Dev Check I have edited my question